# Is it possible to change the commit autoselection to not select local changes during merge in tortoise git?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

If merge commits are commited using tortoise then it automatically selects all changed files (including local working tree changes) in the commit view and not only the ones which are affected by the merge.

If I call `git merge --no-commit <mybranch>` from the commandline git automatically stages all merged files but does not stage files which only contain local changes.

My question is if it is possible to change the autoselection behavior of the tortoise git commit view to match the autostaging behavior which the git merge command has?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, right now (as of TortoiseGit 2.9) this is not possible as TortoiseGit does not have full support for staging yet (cf. https://tortoisegit.org/issue/2299)